# Magento: Out of memory fatal error

Tags: php, magento, out-of-memory

Initially my Magento ecommerce worked fine. After increasing the data on the server I was unable to access the site which gave *out fatal error "Out of memory fatal error"*.

I changed the php.ini option `memory_limit` from `64M` to `512M`. It did not help.

Comment: What's the full error message (including the amounts allocated?).  What does not "working fine" or "not helping" mean?  Does this happen on every page of the system, or just under certain circumstances.  Without these details, it's very unlikely that someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Now to solve the above error follow the under given steps:

**Step 1:** Open your **include/config.php** file and add the following line:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

In this way you will increase the memory limit for your script to 512MB. You should paste the above code in a file which is always invoked when the script is executed.

**Step 2:** Open the **.htaccess** file from the magento root directory and around line 35 replace the

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

with

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

**Step 3:** From the magento root directory rename the **php.ini.sample** file to **php.ini**

**Step 4:** Open the **php.ini** file and replace the

```
memory_limit = 64M
```

with

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

**Step 5:** Go to Admin -> System -> Cache Management and refresh all the cache.
That’s it.